# WordPress installation issue

Tags: php, appserver

After downloaded the WordPress. When i copied entire folder and i paste it into appserv -> www

When i tried to access. from localhost -> www/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php

I am getting 404 not found message.

Please help me how to solve this

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Karthic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use **localhost**/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php than **www**/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php.

Answer (score 1):

@Anoop provided the solution. 
When you manually configure port. 
Sometime its necessary to include port with your localhost. 
Ex: `localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php` 
(8080 is my port number, it can be different for yours)